# Microsoft.VisualBasic does not work in VisualStudio 2017 class library project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a class library in VS2017 in which I would like to use the TextFieldParser from Microsoft.VisualStudio. I had to add the direct reference to that dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
I am also using the File class from System.IO
Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
But the build is failing with messages that do not make sense to me, some of which are

- The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
- The type 'Stream' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
- The type 'TextReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I am not sure if this is due to the new packaging of .NET standard version of the framework

What do I need to do to build the project? Thanks so much!

I have pasted my code below

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Security>> GetSecuritiesAsync()
    {
        string[] lines;
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("securities.csv"))
        {
            var fileText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            lines = fileText.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        }

        //first line header
        var securities = new List<Security>();
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i]))
            {
                string[] attrs = ParseCsv(lines[i]);
                if (attrs.Length == 4)
                {
                    var sec = new Security();
                    int id;
                    if (int.TryParse(attrs[0], out id))
                    {
                        sec.ID = id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sec.Symbol = attrs[1];
                    sec.Name = attrs[2];
                    sec.Sector = attrs[3];

                    securities.Add(sec);
                }
            }
        }
        return securities;
    }

    private string[] ParseCsv(string line)
    {
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(line));

        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

        string[] fields = null;

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            fields = parser.ReadFields();
        }
        parser.Close();
        return fields;


    }
}
```

Comment: You started with the wrong project template, this kind of code cannot compile in any of the NETCore project types.

Comment: Hi Hans, I am not using .NET core. In VS2017 I chose .NET Standard Class library.  That was the only template available for class library in my VS. Anyway I removed the dependency of Microsoft.Visual Basic and I am using nuget package CSVHelper now and I am able to build. However at runtime I am getting exception {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.even after using binding redirect.

Comment: Right, that is the wrong template.  .NET Standard is work-in-progress, but it will never support these classes.  Select the "Windows Classic Desktop" sub-node to find the correct template.  You'll see "Class Library (.NET Framework)".

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you so much for clarifying!